# Merging TypeScript interface declaration for Socket.IO is not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, socket.io

I have been going around in circles looking for how to add a property to an interface for Socket.IO v3. So naturally I have looked in the TypeScript documentation at module augmentation and how to write declaration files but I can't get it working, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. So what's happening is that VSCode is complaining that the `session` property does not exist on the `Handshake` interface.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```ts
// src/types/socket.io/index.d.ts
import { Session, SessionData } from "express-session";
import { EntityContext } from "../../contexts/EntityContext";

declare module "socket.io" {
  interface Handshake {
    session?: Session & Partial<SessionData>;
    sessionID?: string;
    context?: EntityContext;
  }
}
```

**Project Structure**

```
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- /src
    - /types
        - /socket.io
            - index.d.ts
- index.ts
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types",
         "src/types"
      ],
      "paths": {
         "socket.io": ["node_modules/socket.io/dist", "src/types/socket.io"]
      }
   },
   "files": [
      "src/index.ts",
      "src/types/socket.io/index.d.ts"
   ]
}
```

```
// package.json
{
 ...
 "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.21.1",
    "argon2": "^0.27.1",
    "connect-redis": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "socket.io": "^3.1.2",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "0.2.31",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/component-emitter": "^1.2.10",
    "@types/connect-redis": "0.0.16",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.28",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333"
  }
}
```

I don't know if you can tell but I have pretty much grabbed anything and everything I've found to try and solve this but to no avail. I just don't understand how the declarations should work..

If anyone can spot any errors I have made or if you can point me to a guide that can solve this for TypeScript 3 and VSCode I would really appreciate it.

Let me know if you need more information and I will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module declaration is called `'socket.io'`, because you mapped the types in the tsconfig, but this is not necessary. You also mapped the type file itself `"socket.io": ["node_modules/socket.io/dist", "src/types/socket.io"]` which probably breaks the augmentation. Also `node_modules/socket.io/dist` is the wrong path. Correct would be `node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket`. I would recommend to remove the complete `path` configuration, since it will just make things harder.

Without the path configuration you have to tell typescript exactly which module you want to augment as shown in the examples of the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). When you import the unaugmented `Handshake` interface normally it comes from `'socket.io/dist/socket'`. So the path you would use for a normal import, like `import { Handshake } from 'socket.io/dist/socket';`, is also the name for the declared module. You also have to add an import for the original `Handshake` interface, if you want to merge the declarations and not replace it. The `*.d.ts` file should look like this:

```
import { Session, SessionData } from "express-session";
import { EntityContext } from "../../contexts/EntityContext";
// You need to import the original interface to extend it, if you don't,
// you will instead replace the orginal Handshake interface with your own definition. 
import { Handshake } from 'socket.io/dist/socket';

declare module 'socket.io/dist/socket' {
    interface Handshake {
        session?: Session & Partial<SessionData>;
        sessionID?: string;
        context?: EntityContext;
    }
}
```